# Show that no root of the polynomial $x^5 + 21x^4 - 14x^3 + 28x^2 - 7x + 42$ is constructible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, geometric-construction, galois-extensions

> Show that no root of the polynomial $$x^5 + 21x^4 - 14x^3 + 28x^2 - 7x + 42$$ is constructible.

Is it enough to say the degree is 5  is not a power of 2?

Comment: how do you know the polynomial doesn't have a rational root?

Comment: $x^5-32$ has a constructible root

Comment: See Hagen's hint : also think about the coefficients and a criterion you might know for *irreducibility* (which Hagen's polynomial does *not* have). Basically ,saying $5$ is not a power of $2$ *and* something else suffices (with the help of Gauss' theorem).

Comment: Note that your polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (using Eisenstein's criterion for example).  Therefore, the field of extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ given by adding any root of this polynomial has index $5$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$).  If it has a constructible root, then this root must have be in a cascade of field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, each successive index is $2$.  However, $5$ is odd.

Comment: ```gp > polgalois(x^5+21*x^4-14*x^3+28*x^2-7*x+42)
%1 = [120, -1, 1, "S5"]```

Comment: Well, it is 7-Eisenstein irreducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prove the following assertion.  If $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ such that $n$ has an odd prime factor, then the roots of $f(x)$ are not constructible.

The proof is done by proving the contrapositive statement.  We just have to show that the minimal polynomial of any constructible number $\alpha$ has degree $2^k$ for some integer $k\ge 0$.  However, this is simply because there exist field extensions
$$\Bbb{Q}=F_0<F_1<F_2<\ldots < F_k=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$$
such that $[F_i:F_{i-1}]=2$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$.  Therefore, $[F_k:\Bbb Q]=2^k$, proving the claim.

The converse doesn't hold.  The roots of the irreducible polynomial $x^4-x-1$ are not constructible.  This is because the Galois group of $x^4-x-1$ is the symmetric group $S_4$, which is not a $2$-group.  (See [example 3.2](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf) of this article.)