# How to show $\sqrt[17]{11}$ is not constructible (through ruler and compass construction)

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-construction

I understand that for a number to be constructible it must be a membeer of the field of constructible numbers $C$ such that $ 0,1 \in C $ and which is closed under addition, subtraction, division, multiplication and square roots.

So is it sufficient to say that $\sqrt[17]{11}$ is not constructible since there is no way to generate the 17th root using ruler and compass construction since 17 is a prime number (and so can definitely not be obtained through repeated square roots)?

Comment: No, that's not enough as stated, but you can sharpen this argument using the concept of the degree of field extensions. It turns out $ \sqrt[17]{11} $ does in fact have degree $ 17 $ over $ \mathbf Q $, and any algebraic number of odd degree can't be constructible for a reason analogous to your argument.

Comment: $\alpha=\sqrt[17]{11}$ is root of $X^{17}-11$, which is Eisenstein, so it generates a field extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ of degree 17, which is not a power of 2..

Comment: See my answer here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644970/show-that-no-root-of-the-polynomial-x5-21x4-14x3-28x2-7x-42-is-c/3645774#3645774).